# SpecFlow - C# - var abc =table.CreateInstance<>() null

Tags: c#, testing, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I have this scenario. Basically I want to log in with certain roles and then enumerate through the table of values at a point in my test to see if they are all viewable.

```
Scenario Outline: View something with user.
    Given I navigate to the application with "<Role>"
    When I view something for "<SubRole>"
    Then all things should be viewable for "<SubRole>"
        | Sequence | Things |
        | 1        | thing1 |
        | 2        | thing2 |
        | 3        | thing3 |
        | 4        | thing4 |

    @Dev
    Examples:
        | Role       | SubRole|
        | System role| user1  |
```

```
 [Then(@"all things should be viewable for ""(.*)""")]
        public void ThenAllThingsShouldBeViewableFor(string subRole, Table table)
        {
         
             var things = table.CreateInstance<AllThings>();

   foreach (var stuff in things)
           {
             //code to check if all things in table are viewable
           }
```

```
public class AllThings
{
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
    public string Things{ get; set; }

}
```

However var things = null for both Sequence and Things and i cant figure out why? The table populates fine but I cant assign it to the variable 'things' as it just returns null

Then when it comes to the foreach loop i get a 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also as you are expecting an Enumerable, you have to use `CreateSet` and not `CreateInstance`.

So it should look like this:

```cs
[Then(@"all things should be viewable for ""(.*)""")]
public void ThenAllThingsShouldBeViewableFor(string subRole, Table table)
{
    var things = table.CreateSet<AllThings>();
    foreach (var stuff in things)
    {
          //code to check if all things in table are viewable
    }
}
```

See docs for this: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Step-Definitions.html#table-or-multi-line-text-arguments

Comment: I always thought the `Table` was the last argument. Did that change?

Comment: No, we didn't change in this part of the code anything since years.

Comment: when i used CreateSet instead of CreateInstance it worked! thanks!

Comment: The Table parameter hast to be the last one. I corrected the answer.